# Exclude collectives from search

Tags: support, status-completed, search, collectives

I can filter posts with collectives, like `collective:"Google Cloud"`, but is there a way to exclude them from search, like I do with tags(`-[tag]`)?

Comment: i must often switch to google to find things i want to use, with so many programmers there must be a better search

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I've updated the status of the question which will add the item to our backlog. Together with the dev team, we'll see how and when we could be doing this. We'll make sure to update this post whenever we have more clarity :).

Comment: @nbk apples and oranges, the site search is the best tool if you want to do a filtered search (like finding things that still need answering), google is better if you seek an answer to a question you have yourself.

Comment: @Gimby the site earcch fidns absolutely nothing of omportance, i test this alsmost daily, the only think i ca fid when i go to my user page and enter specific search words that i know i have used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to *exclude* questions related to a specific Collective has been added to the search feature.  This is done using the syntax `collective:-"Name"` and results in a search that excludes all tags associated with the Collective.

For example, you can use `collective:-"Google Cloud"`, which will give you search results as if you excluded every [tag associated with the Google Cloud Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=tags):

Note: the in-product search tips/search help hasn't yet been updated to include this syntax.

[image: search results page showing all tags associated with collective have been excluded]

Comment: Hold on, that sounds...broken.  As in, I think it does exactly what is advertised, which is blot out questions based on a collective, but that's a *whole lot* of exclusions.  If the collective includes too much then this could be an issue for folks looking for questions that are only tangentially related to a collective.

Comment: One use case is to search for questions that are not in the collective (due to not being tagged with a collective tag) but perhaps should be. Or to look for recently added tags that might be considered for inclusion.